# WSO2: configuring and publishing to specific tenants

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Hi I am using WSO2 API Manager 1.9.0. I have created an API, and I want to publish it to a specific tenant, I also specified it to be available to the tenant I created only. I have created my tenant on admin (http://:9443/carbon) and configured the external store, but when i try to publish  I always get Failed to publish API to external store. Not sure what I missed between configuring the tenant and the external store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your endpoint should be the endpoint of the external store.

http://localhost:9763/store

Credentials should be  (external store's) tenant's username and password.
id can be anything you prefer to have and Display is the name that will be displayed, which also can be anything you preferred.

If you are trying to publish from the supertenant mode to external store's tenant mode, you have to do the configuration in super tenant's external-api-stores.xml. Or else in tenant's if you need to publish from tenant to tenant in external store. You have to login to management console accordingly.

Please refer this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publish+to+multiple+external+API+stores)

Comment: Thanks @Ushani, very helpful, managed to publish to multiple external stores. I was getting the external-api-stores.xml configurations all wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Disregard,
The **id="tenantName"** has to be the same as the tenant name

http://localhost:9763/store

```
    <ExternalAPIStore **id="Store2"** type="wso2" className="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.publishers.WSO2APIPublisher">
        <DisplayName>Store1</DisplayName>
        <Endpoint>http://localhost:9763/store</Endpoint>
        <Username>xxxx</Username>
        <Password>xxxx</Password>
    </ExternalAPIStore>
```

Comment: Id can be anything you prefer to have and Display is the name that will be displayed, which also can be anything you preferred.